# T-SQL format date by pattern

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2005

Is possible change format date by specific pattern ? I need to made a function which has a two parameters. First is date and second is pattern. I need convert more date variants. Goal this function is change US and European date format.

For example i need convert

EU: dd:MM:yyyy hh:mm:ss
to
US: MM:dd:yyyy hh:mm:ss

On another page i need change

EU: dd/MM/yyyy
to
US: MM/dd/yyyy

And i have a several next variant to convert

And i want to made a similar function

```
Formater(euDate, pattern)
BEGIN
....

RETURN usDate
```

My production server is unfortunately SQL server 2005 and doesn't support function `FORMAT()`. And function `CONVERT()` doesn't support some variant of date, which i need convert. So in my current solution i parse EU date at individualy parts `(@day = day(@euDate), @month, @year, ...)` and join them in new string . And i compare it with input parameter in pattern and return CASE which is equal like pattern. I want to this function make general and simplier.

Thank you for Your advice.

Comment: Can you use a CLR assembly? Those work in 2005, and from what I remember, the later versions of SQL Server's new FORMAT() method is basically just a wrapper around the standard Common Language Runtime formatting methods.

Answer (score 1):

**You almost certainly can use the `convert` function.**  You can read more about all the options [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

If there is some obscure invariant you need, check out [this blog by Anubhav Goyal](https://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/).

Comment: I believe the downvote came because the question specified that the `CONVERT` function does not handle all variants, though this assertion did not come with examples. I would like to see examples of the variants that do not work with `CONVERT` to see if we can figure out a solution.

Comment: @BrianPayne  This is odd since the cases the OP needs appear covered.  Moreover, the second link I provided has a function which basically can be used to build whatever is needed.  I edited my answer to say as much.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i don't downvote your answer, but for example i have a format dd.MM.yyyy time and this format i don't find in Convert function.

Comment: The function clearly has 01/01/2015, which seems sufficient in most cases.